# How do I write a function that will return a list that adds the reocurrnce each Character in a word

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to at least start this. It is in python.

```
def countChars(inString):
    sentence = raw_input()
    while a in sentence:
        sentence.append[]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are you trying to achieve? Give a sample input and an output.

Comment: Are you trying to count how many times each letter appears? Or convert the sentence into a list of letters?

Comment: Example: countChars(‘banana’) will return [‘b’, 1, ‘a’, 3, ‘n’, 2]

Comment: just use sentence.count('a') to count occurence of particular char in a string

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [dictionary](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: It keeps on saying that inString is not defined

Comment: Why do you have to use a list for this. You should use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this and keep count of the characters. That would be the way to do something like this.

Comment: It is part of the assignment

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
def count_chars(str):
    letters = dict()
    for c in iter(str):
        letters.setdefault(c, 0)
        letters[c] += 1

    print(letters.items())
```